# ZingChart Series value box not showing despite identical data and options to a series value box that does show on horizontal bar chart

Tags: charts, zingchart

Could someone please explain to me why the first series value box is not showing up but the rest of them are?  I've been banging my head against the wall on this for an hour now.  I've faked data below, but the outcome is the same.  Thank you in advance!

```js
var ctFin = 60;
var myConfig = {
  "type": "hbar",
  "font-family": "proxima_nova_rgregular",
  "title": {
    "text": "MINUTES <b>IN ZONES</b>",
    "font-family": "proxima_nova_rgregular",
    "background-color": "none",
    "font-color": "#39393d",
    "font-size": "22px",
    "adjustLayout": true,
    "height": "35px",
    "padding-bottom": "23px"
  },
  "plot": {
    "bars-overlap": "1%",
    "borderRadius": "0 3px 3px 0",
    "hover-state": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "animation": {
      "delay": 300,
      "effect": 4,
      "speed": "500",
      "method": "0",
      "sequence": "3"
    }
  },
  "plotarea": {
    "height": "99px",
    "border-left": "3px solid #39393d",
    "padding-left": "3px",
    "margin": "0 0 0 3px"
  },
  "scale-x": {
    "line-color": "none",
    "tick": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "guide": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "item": {
      "visible": false
    }
  },
  "scale-y": {
    "visible": false,
    "guide": {
      "visible": false
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "values": [5],
      "bar-width": "20px",
      "background-color": "#cdcccc",
      "tooltip": {
        "visible": false
      },
      "value-box": {
        "placement": "top-out",
        "text": "%v",
        "decimals": 0,
        "font-color": "#35353b",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "alpha": 1,
        "rules": [
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 > 35",
            "placement": "top-in",
          },
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 < 25",
            "placement": "top-in",
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "values": [5],
      "bar-width": "20px",
      "background-color": "#71cbdc",
      "tooltip": {
        "visible": false
      },
      "value-box": {
        "placement": "top-out",
        "text": "%v",
        "decimals": 0,
        "font-color": "#35353b",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "alpha": 1,
        "rules": [
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 > 35",
            "placement": "top-in",
          },
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 < 25",
            "placement": "top-in",
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "values": [5],
      "bar-width": "20px",
      "background-color": "#8cc541",
      "tooltip": {
        "visible": false
      },
      "value-box": {
        "placement": "top-out",
        "text": "%v",
        "decimals": 0,
        "font-color": "#35353b",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "alpha": 1,
        "rules": [
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 > 35",
            "placement": "top-in",
          },
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 < 25",
            "placement": "top-in",
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "values": [5],
      "bar-width": "20px",
      "background-color": "#d96c27",
      "tooltip": {
        "visible": false
      },
      "value-box": {
        "placement": "top-out",
        "text": "%v",
        "decimals": 0,
        "font-color": "#35353b",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "alpha": 1,
        "rules": [
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 > 35",
            "placement": "top-in",
          },
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 < 25",
            "placement": "top-in",
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "values": [5],
      "bar-width": "20px",
      "background-color": "#ea2629",
      "tooltip": {
        "visible": false
      },
      "value-box": {
        "placement": "top-out",
        "text": "%v",
        "decimals": 0,
        "font-color": "#35353b",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "alpha": 1,
        "rules": [
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 > 35",
            "placement": "top-in",
          },
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 < 25",
            "placement": "top-in",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
zingchart.render({
  id: 'myChart',
  data: myConfig,
  height: 140,
  width: 330
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but changing your plot area height to 1px instead of 99 fixes the issue? : http://jsbin.com/huretuquzo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @axlj said, adjusting your plotarea will fix the issue. You defined a plotarea less than the total heigh of all your bars. You defined  `barWidth:'20px'` so total height was 100px (5bars * 20). If you define `plotarea:'100px'` it will work fine. In the end you don't need to specify the plotarea height though. I took the liberty to merge some of your JSON attributes as well.

```js
var ctFin = 60;
var myConfig = {
  "type": "hbar",
  "font-family": "proxima_nova_rgregular",
  "title": {
    "text": "MINUTES <b>IN ZONES</b>",
    "font-family": "proxima_nova_rgregular",
    "background-color": "none",
    "font-color": "#39393d",
    "font-size": "22px",
    "adjustLayout": true,
    "height": "35px",
    "padding-bottom": "23px"
  },
  "plot": {
    "bar-width":20,
    "bars-overlap": "1%",
    "borderRadius": "0 3px 3px 0",
    "hover-state": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "animation": {
      "delay": 300,
      "effect": 4,
      "speed": "500",
      "method": "0",
      "sequence": "3"
    },
    "value-box": {
        "placement": "top-in",
        "text": "%v",
        "decimals": 0,
        "font-color": "#35353b",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "alpha": 1,
        "rules": [
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 > 35",
            "placement": "top-in",
          },
          {
            "rule": "%v / " + ctFin + " * 100 < 25",
            "placement": "top-in",
          }
        ]
      }
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "visible": false
  },
  "plotarea": {
    "border-left": "3px solid #39393d",
    "padding-left": "3px",
    "margin": "0 0 0 3px"
  },
  "scale-x": {
    "visible": false
  },
  "scale-y": {
    "visible": false,
    "guide": {
      "visible": false
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "values": [5],
      "background-color": "#cdcccc",
    },
    {
      "values": [5],
      "background-color": "#71cbdc",
    },
    {
      "values": [5],
      "background-color": "#8cc541",
    },
    {
      "values": [5],
      "background-color": "#d96c27",
    },
    {
      "values": [5],
      "background-color": "#ea2629",
    }
  ]
};
zingchart.render({
  id: 'myChart',
  data: myConfig,
  height: 140,
  width: 330
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```